# Placing tick marks between bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the `diamonds` data set in the `ggplot2` package, I can generate the following chart.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

diamond.summary <- 
  diamonds %>%
  mutate(carat = ifelse(runif(nrow(.)) < 0.05, NA_real_, carat)) %>%
  group_by(carat_quintile = ntile(carat, 5)) %>%
  summarise(avg_price = mean(price))

diamond.summary %>%
  filter(!is.na(carat_quintile)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(carat_quintile, avg_price)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           color = "black",
           width = 1) + 
  scale_x_continuous("Carat percentile",
                     breaks = 1:6 - 0.5,
                     labels = seq(0,100, by = 20)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(0, 1.1* max(diamond.summary$avg_price)))
```

[image]

So far, so easy. However, I would also like to display the average price of the missing entries alongside the chart. Similar to the following:
[image]

```
diamond.summary %>%
  mutate(Facet = is.na(carat_quintile),
         carat_quintile_noNA = ifelse(Facet, "Unknown", carat_quintile)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = carat_quintile_noNA, y = avg_price, fill = Facet)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_grid(~Facet, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = (0:6) - 0.5)
```

However, when I try to perform the same trick using `scale_x_continuous`, I get the error `Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`. When I try to use `scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(0:6 + 0.5))` for example, the axis ticks and labels disappear.

My question is, how can I get the same faceted chart above with the tick marks in the first panel placed as in the first chart in this post? Advice about chart design could be an acceptable solution, but I don't think all problems like this are solvable with a redesign.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, but maybe you use something like that + scale_x_discrete("carat_quintile_noNA", labels = c("1" = "-0.5","2" = "0.5", "3" = "1.5","4" = "2.5","5" = "3.5", "Unknown" = "4.5"))

Comment: Nope that places the tick marks in the middle of the bars. I'd like them between the bars.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick is to convert your factor to a numeric, assigning a magic number to the unknown quantity. (`ggplot2` will not plot bars with true `NA` values.) Then use `scale_x_continuous`

```
diamond.summary %>%
  mutate(Facet = is.na(carat_quintile),
         carat_quintile_noNA = ifelse(Facet, "Unknown", carat_quintile),
         ## 
         ## 99 is a magic number.  For our plot, it just has
         ## to be larger than 5. The value 6 would be a natural
         ## choice, but this means that the x tick marks would 
         ## overflow ino the 'unknown' facet.  You could choose
         ## choose 7 to avoid this, but any large number works.  
         ## I used 99 to make it clear that it's magic.
         numeric = ifelse(Facet, 99, carat_quintile)) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x = numeric, y = avg_price, fill = Facet)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1) + 
  facet_grid(~Facet, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0:5 + 0.5, 99),
                     labels = c(paste0(c(0:5) * 20, "%"), "Unknown"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to approach a bit differently, and reposition the *bars* instead of the ticks, using `position_nudge`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

diamond.summary <- 
  diamonds %>%
  mutate(carat = ifelse(runif(nrow(.)) < 0.05, NA_real_, carat)) %>%
  group_by(carat_quintile = ntile(carat, 5)) %>%
  summarise(avg_price = mean(price))

# nudge bars to the left
diamond.summary %>%
  filter(!is.na(carat_quintile)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(carat_quintile, avg_price)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           color = "black",
           width = 1,
           position=position_nudge((x=-1))) + 
  scale_x_continuous("Carat percentile",
                     breaks = 1:6 - 0.5,
                     labels = seq(0,100, by = 20)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(0, 1.1* max(diamond.summary$avg_price)))
```

[image: nudge bars left]

```
# nudge bars to the right
diamond.summary %>%
  filter(!is.na(carat_quintile)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(carat_quintile, avg_price)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           color = "black",
           width = 1,
           position=position_nudge((x=1))) + 
  scale_x_continuous("Carat percentile",
                     breaks = 1:6 - 0.5,
                     labels = seq(0,100, by = 20)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(0, 1.1* max(diamond.summary$avg_price)))
```

[image: nudge bars right]

Comment: This is a novel solution. Unfortuantely, the appearance with the facet doesn't look quite right.